# Windows Phone 8.1 Send HTML mail from code

Tags: html, windows, email

I'm trying to open mail application with it's content defined in code, but when i send it, gmail / oulook ... display as a plain text instead of HTML.

```
private async void SendEmail(string url)
{

    EmailMessage mail = new EmailMessage();
    mail.Subject = "test";
    mail.Body = string.Format("<!DOCTYPE html><html><body><image src=\"{0}\"/></body></html>", url);

    await EmailManager.ShowComposeNewEmailAsync(mail);

}
```

How can i force content to display as HTML instead of plain text ?

EDIT : Screenshot of avaiable properties :
[image]

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You simply cannot. Whether this is a limitation related to safety or missing functionality Windows Phone can not send HTML-formatted email, not by code or by mail client.

All you can do is use your own backend server to send html formated emails.