# Windows Phone 8.1 : Unable to send html formatted Mail via default mail client

Tags: c#, .net, windows-phone-8, windows-phone-8.1

My Scenario is to send mail via windows phone 8.1 default mail client. I have already configured a mail account.

I am trying to set Html Content to body section of mail client. It doesn't get rendered automatically. It shows html content as it is.

Is there any other possible way to show formatted text inside body section of default mail client.

[image]

This is how the content shows on mail client.

[image]

My purpose is to send the formatted text(rendered text) here. Not the html content. Any help is much appreciated.

Comment: possible duplicate of [Windows Phone 8.1 Send HTML mail from code](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/24759636/windows-phone-8-1-send-html-mail-from-code)

Answer (score 0):

There are no available APIs or libraries for windows phone to send a html email. Try send html email from web service instead.