# How to send a link in mail in Windows Phone 8.1 using C# and XAML

Tags: windows-phone-8.1

i want to share a item of my OneDrive, so i am sending an Email with the link of that item , but what i want is that, the user should get a hyperlink but i am not able to generate a hyperlink.

The code which i am using is as follows :

```
private async void shareOneDrvItem(string SharefilePath)
{
    var emailMessage = new Windows.ApplicationModel.Email.EmailMessage();
    emailMessage.Body =  SharefilePath ;
    emailMessage.Subject = "Shared Link from OneDrive";
    await ApplicationModel.Email.EmailManager.ShowComposeNewEmailAsync(emailMessage);
}   

    Please help me guys.
```

Comment: Does changing this `emailMessage.Body =  SharefilePath;` to `emailMessage.Body =  "<a href='sharefilepath'>SharefilePath</a>;` solve it?

Comment: I tried this, but it is not working

Comment: I just found out you can't using the above classes ... http://stackoverflow.com/questions/24759636/windows-phone-8-1-send-html-mail-from-code ... but this question might help you find other way ... http://stackoverflow.com/questions/12732263/how-do-i-send-an-email-from-a-winrt-windows-store-application

Comment: Possible duplicate http://stackoverflow.com/q/24759636/2827823